# Is there a way to "return" from a block expression?

Tags: rust, expression

You can return from a function before reaching the last statement can be done using `return`:

```
fn example() -> i32 {
    if true {
        return 1;
    }

    0 // this line is never reached
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar with block expressions?

```
let foo = {
    if true {
        // somehow "return" so that foo is 1
    }

    0 // this line is never reached
};
```

In this example I could have used an `if`-`else`, but I'm asking about block expressions in general.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov because using "return 1" inside a block expression returns from the entire function the expression is in, not just the expression. If you're asking "why not use a function", readability

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[From Rust 1.65.0, it is possible to name the block and break from it](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#break-from-labeled-blocks):

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 'bar: {
        if true {
            break 'bar 1;
        }

        0 // this line is never reached
    };
}
```

---

Before Rust 1.65.0, there was a well known "`loop` hack":

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = loop {
        if true {
            break 1;
        }

        break 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: Can the loop hack be used to break the hacky outer loop from within a legit inner loop? Something like `break 'outer value;`?

Comment: @BallpointBen no, you'd need labels for that.

Comment: FYI: `cargo clippy` complains about the loop hack; it says *"this loop never actually loops"*.

Comment: You can now break from a labeled block since 1.65.0 https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html

Answer (score 12):

You could also use an immediately invoked closure.

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = (|| {
        if true {
            return 1;
        }
        
        0
    })();
}
```

My bet would be that LLVM is smart enough to optimize the function call out in release builds.

Comment: This is a good hack. Might it have issues with needing to `move` variables into the closure though?

Answer (score 8):

*Edit:* This feature has been [stabilized in Rust 1.65.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#break-from-labeled-blocks).

---

This feature has been proposed: [RFC 2046 - break label value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2046-label-break-value.md). It uses the [`break`-label](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/keyword.break.html) syntax (used in loops) and is available as an unstable feature.

So this will work on the *nightly* compiler:

```
#![feature(label_break_value)]

let foo = 'a: {
    if true {
        break 'a 1;
    }
    0
};
```

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:*
[It's now possible to break from labeled blocks](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#break-from-labeled-blocks)

---

*Original answer:*

I don't think it's currently possible but I found this tracking issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48594